# Fade elements in on scroll with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, opacity

I am creating a timeline of events on my website, and I am trying to get each element (with a class '.event') to fade in as you scroll down through timeline. I am having issues - they all fade in together at the same time rather than individually.

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.event').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    }); 

});
```

});

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle or something with your markup and styles and code? I put your JS into a JSFiddle I just created and it works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/drn33/. We'll need to see what's different in your case to see why it isn't working.

Comment: Yeah sure here's a link http://jsfiddle.net/edharrison89/V5DU7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edharrison89/V5DU7/) this seems to be linked to a styling and/or markup issue.

Here's an updated version of your JSFiddle that works with your code and your markup:  http://jsfiddle.net/2yMn4/2/. It messes up your layout a little bit, so you might need to rethink the structure, but hopefully that points you in the right direction. The main change that got it started working was switching your `.event` class to be relatively positioned. Then removing the second `.posts-timeline` article and `.posts` div.

```
.event {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 210px;
    z-index: 100;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```